# Unable to connect to public RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've been struggling with this for 2 days now. Did a lot of research and troubleshooting for the most obvious things related to the connection. I'll enumerate all I did and how is everything is setup.

1. I created a custom VPC for this in the 10.0.0.0/16 CIDR
2. I created 6 subnets, 2 public, 2 private and 2 db public subnets.
   [image]
3. Created the route tables for the subnets.
   [image]
4. The public subnet and the db subnet have a route to the IGW
   [image]
5. The internet gateway is attached to the VPC.
   [image]
6. The database has been created with "public access" and also in the public db subnets.
   [image]
7. The Security Group has been updated with inbound rule. Eventually I would like to only connect from a given set of IPs but for now I'm opening to all IPs for troubleshooting.
   [image]

So until this point according to all the tutorials, videos that I've watched I should be able to connect to the RDS instance.

One of the suggested troubleshooting steps was to try and TELNET into the instance.
I redacted the endpoint but that's the one I got from the RDS panel.

```
➜  proj git:(main) ✗ telnet REDACTED.REDACTED.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
Trying XX.XXX.39.69...
telnet: connect to address XX.XXX.39.69: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Another suggestion was to try from a different network. I did try on cellular data and also from a VPS in DigitalOcean, same effect.

Hope someone can guide me on this because it's driving me crazy...

EDIT1: ENI Public IP address does match the resolved IP from TELNET
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please move your question to serverfault.com where this is on-topic. StackOverflow.com should be used for programming questions

Comment: You could check the ENIs that have been associated to your RDS, and if it matches the IP resolving in your telnet test.

Comment: @palvarez yes it does, I updated the question with the details at the bottom, I also shared the IP address maybe it helps to see if it's something on my network, it's listening to all IPv4 addresses at the moment.

Comment: Your IP addresses do not match. You are using `XX.XXX.39.69` which is different then `52.8.164.150`?

Comment: @Marcin sorry about the confusion, those were different attempts. I tried a lot of time creating and re-creating the environment. I found the issue, it seem to be something wrong with my account, apparently its common, found other threads were people were having the same issue, I decided to create another account and use the exact terraform plan I used for this one and it works without any issue. I raised a support ticket but they closed it because I need to pay for technical support... :s

Answer (score 1):

**To reproduce your situation, I did the following:**

- Created a VPC across 2 AZs, each with 1 Public, 1 Private and 1 "DB" subnet

[image: VPC Architecture]

(I then renamed `private3` and `private4` as my DB subnets.)

- Edited the route table associate with the "DB" Subnets:

[image: Route Table]

- Made sure that Route Table was associated with my "DB" subnets:

[image: Subnet associations]

- Created a new **DB Subnet Group** containing the two "DB" subnets
- Launched an **Amazon RDS Database**:

  - PostgreSQL 14.6
  - Dev/Test, Single DB instance
  - Instance type: `db.t3.micro`
  - **Public access** = Yes
  - Used the above **DB Subnet Group**
  - Create new **Security Group**
- Confirmed that the auto-created **security group** permits Inbound port 5432 to my IP address (It did!)
- Connected to the database using `psql` from my laptop:

```
psql -h stack-db.cdigff1pjpzh.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U postgres 
Password for user postgres: 

psql (15.2, server 14.6)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=>
```

**It connected just fine!**

Please compare my steps with yours to see what might be different.

Comment: Thank you for your post. You gave me the idea to create another account and test my terraform plan and as you say, it works as expected. Apparently there is something wrong with my account, some people are experiencing the same issue something like a "soft block" were you can't connect to your own resources.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new AWS account and run the exact same configuration and it worked without any issue... I found some other reports were people are experiencing the same issue (see link below). Apparently it happens for accounts that were blocked/restricted and when they lift the restriction something stays broken. Sad news is that it requires technical assistance from AWS to solve and they won't accept the issue without raising a technical issue which requires a subscription...

[SSH connection drops after couple seconds on every new instance EC2, then any attempt to reconnect always return connection timed out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772542/ssh-connection-drops-after-couple-seconds-on-every-new-instance-ec2-then-any-at)

FINAL RESOLUTION FROM AWS.

I did some research using internal tool and see that resources in your account are under restricted access. I see that account was reinstated recently from suspended state. When account are suspended, the resources in all the region will be in restricted access. After the account reinstated, this restriction should be removed in every region manually. I assume this was not done from our end thus I see the restriction.

Please accept my apologize on behalf of the AWS for the inconvenience caused due to the same.

Moving further, I contacted my internal team and got the restriction removed in all the region for your account. I can confirm the restriction has been removed now. Please confirm whether you could connect to instance now.

I once again apologize for the inconvenience caused. Please do not hesitate to get back to me if you have any other queries. I will be happy to assist you.

Thank you and have a nice day!

We value your feedback. Please share your experience by rating this and other correspondences in the AWS Support Center. You can rate a correspondence by selecting the stars in the top right corner of the correspondence.

Best regards,
Ruchikka C.
Amazon Web Services