# Unable to connect to Amazon RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to an RDS instance via my Macbook (M1, Sonoma 14.2.1), and am constantly running into this error. Initially I thought the error was that my instance was not publicly accessible, which I have now changed.

Error message here:

```
Unable to connect to the database: HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_amazon_rds_host
at Client._connectionCallback (/Users/as/Desktop/sample_app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:134:24)
at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/Users/as/Desktop/sample_app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:327:19)
at Client._handleErrorEvent (/Users/as/Desktop/sample_app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:337:19)
at Connection.emit (node:events:519:28)
at Socket.reportStreamError (/Users/as/Desktop/sample_app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:58:12)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    parent: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_amazon_rds_host
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {
        errno: -3008,
        code: 'ENOTFOUND',
        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
        hostname: 'your_amazon_rds_host'
    },
    original: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_amazon_rds_host
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {
        errno: -3008,
        code: 'ENOTFOUND',
        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
        hostname: 'your_amazon_rds_host'
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, here are some relevant details I have included in my .env file:

```
AWS RDS Instance:
Endpoint: database-1.servername.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Username: postgres
Password: RandomPassword
DB Instance Identifier: database-1
Database Port: 5432
```

Security Group Inbound Rules

```
Type: All traffic
Protocol: All
Port Range: All
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When you say that you are "constantly running into this error", are you saying that it _sometimes_ gives the error, or it has _always_ had an error? That is, have you _ever_ been able to connect to the RDS database? First thing would be to check whether you can resolve the DNS name. If you are on Linux, you can use `nslookup database-1.servername.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`. Or, you can `ping database-1.servername.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` and see whether it displays an IP address (ignore whether Ping works). Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Please Edit your Question and include the configuration of the Security Group Inbound rules.

Comment: Thanks - I have added the rules now. 
It is always an error, not seen it work at all. 
It does appear that I can resolve DNS name, since when I pinged the database, it showed me an IP address, although the Ping itself failed.

Comment: You might want to compare what you did with the steps shown in: [Unable to connect to public RDS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657541/174777) Also, try using a different program to connect to Postgres -- it might give a more friendly error message

Comment: There is some inconsistency here, you are trying to connect to ```hostname: 'your_amazon_rds_host'```, but the instance name that you have noted is ```database-1```, plus the endpoint is ```database-1.servername.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com```. What is the actual public hostname?

Comment: When you made your instance publicly available, did you use the [`--apply_immdiately`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html#USER_ModifyInstance.ApplyImmediately) flag?  Otherwise, it won't change until the next maintenance window.

Comment: Can you post your sequelize code, i.e how you're connecting. Where have you defined `your_amazon_rds_host` because `syscall: 'getaddrinfo' ` is telling you that the `getaddrinfo()` function basically cant get an ip for `your_amazon_rds_host`.

Answer (score 1):

please check all these think

The error message you are encountering (getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_amazon_rds_host)

Check the RDS Instance Status

Correct Hostname or IP Address

Security Group and Firewall Settings

Comment: Thanks for your response.
RDS Instance Status is 'Available'
Hostname is copied directly from the dashboard, and is correct. 
Not sure what to look for in the Security Group, but see as 'default', and '1 Permission entry' under 'Inbound rules count'.

Answer (score 1):

Check your VPC and subnet in which you created your RDS

- is it a public subnet or private subnet ? - use a public subnet
- check NACL and Route table settings too - default ones allow all, but when you create new ones, they block all.
- is there a Igw connected to your Route table ? - required for internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can resolve the DNS name but are still unable to connect, focus on the Sequelize configuration and network settings.

The fact that you can resolve the DNS name of your RDS instance to an IP address is a good sign. It means that your MacBook is correctly resolving the RDS endpoint. However, the ping failure could be due to AWS security settings, as [AWS often blocks ICMP (ping) traffic](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/icmp/).

Make sure your Sequelize setup in the Node.js application is using the correct hostname. Replace `'your_amazon_rds_host'` with the [actual endpoint of your RDS instance](https://www.intuz.com/cloud/docs/how-to/how-to-find-rds-end-point).

Your Sequelize updated [configuration](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#configuration) would be:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// Replace these values with the actual details from your .env file
const sequelize = new Sequelize('databaseName', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'database-1.servername.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', // Correct host
  dialect: 'postgres',
  port: 5432
});

sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

Try also to use a different PostgreSQL client (like pgAdmin or DBeaver) to test the connection with the same credentials. That can help determine if the issue is with Sequelize or the network.
Double-check that the [security group attached to your RDS instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) allows inbound traffic on port 5432 from your IP address. Also, make sure any [Network Access Control Lists (NACLs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) are not blocking this traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise doing the basic checks to confirm that your machine can reach the database. The error seems to be coming from your application and not the database. Forget about connecting to the database for a second.

1. Confirm that there is no typo in the hostname you are connecting to.
2. Confirm if the hostname can be resolved to an IP on your Mac. Do a nslookup to the hostname from your terminal.
3. Try pinging the hostname or IP to confirm if you get a response.
4. Try to telnet the hostname/ IP on the port it listens on.

We will know where to focus our attention on (application, network or database) after doing these checks.